# Sort divs by multiple data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I sort by both of the data attributes? First I need to sort by `discount` and then sort by `weight`.

```html
<div id="list">
    <div class="row" data-weight="1" data-discount=0>banana</div>
    <div class="row" data-weight="3" data-discount=30>apple</div>
    <div class="row" data-weight="4" data-discount=0>avocado</div>
    <div class="row" data-weight="8" data-discount=15>milk</div>
</div>
```

```js
function sortOrder() {
  divList.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return $(b).data("order")-$(a).data("order");
  });
  $(".list").html(divList);
}
```

Comment: How are you generating the data?

Comment: I removed the PHP tag from your question as it's not at all relevant

Answer (score 2):

Your current `sort()` logic shows how to do this for a single attribute. For multiple attributes you simply need to amend the logic to cater for cases where the values are the same, which can be seen below.

Note that this logic can be made less verbose, but I left it this way to make the flow more obvious.

```js
var $divList = $('#list .row');

function sortOrder() {
  $divList.sort(function(a, b) {
    var $a = $(a), $b = $(b);
    
    if ($a.data('discount') < $b.data('discount')) {
      return 1;
    } else if ($a.data('discount') > $b.data('discount')) {
      return -1;
    }
    
    if ($a.data('weight') < $b.data('weight')) {
      return 1;
    } else if ($a.data('weight') > $b.data('weight')) {
      return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
  });

  $("#list").append($divList);
}

sortOrder();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class="row" data-weight="1" data-discount=0>banana</div>
  <div class="row" data-weight="3" data-discount=30>apple</div>
  <div class="row" data-weight="4" data-discount=0>avocado</div>
  <div class="row" data-weight="8" data-discount=15>milk</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need say first 2 div have discount it's show in first two then show rest of the div by ordering weight. but your answer is not working which i want. please have a look

Comment: That is exactly what this code is doing. The divs are first ordered by `discount`, which puts `apple` first, then `milk`. If the `discount` values match then it orders by `weight`, which puts `avocado` third and `banana` fourth. What output are you expecting?